# What's my real rep?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

I answered a question, got 4 upvotes, yet my rep is only 103. Here's a screenshot of what I see on my profile page:

[image: WTF]

It says it's 103 on the bar above, yet 149 just below my profile image. What's going on here?

Answer (score 5):

It appears you have two different accounts:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/15794/alex
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/10538/alex

In your picture, it doesn't show the 'private' fields 'Real Name' or 'email'.  That indicates you are looking at a profile that is not the same as the one you are logged in as.

A friendly neighborhood moderator should be able to merge these for you.

Comment: Well spotted. I looked but completely missed that.

Comment: I merged the accounts.

Answer (score 2):

I'll merge account [15794](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/15794/alex) into [10538](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/10538/alex) as the latter has your answer.

Account 15794 uses a Yahoo OpenID, 10583 a Google.

Please make sure you log into the Google account and edit both profiles to indicate this.

Post a comment on this answer so I know you've done it.